# Show multiple tablix for each selection

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-tablix

I am doing a report with parameters: date(dataInicio, dataFim) and location(unidade). I can select multiple locations.
When I select more than one location it shows me the result of only one location (only one tablix).
What I want it is to show one tablix for each checked location.

[image]

Comment: Assuming that your main dataset contains the correct data (all selected locations) then you probably just need to a parent group that groups by location.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows displayed by the report is controlled by the row grouping in your table. The screenshot doesn't show how many groups you have or what they are grouped on, but you would most likely want a parent row group that is grouped on location. After that, you can have any other level of detail groups as needed. Finally, you would have a details row group (should be there by default) that is not grouped by anything. This allows the report to show all of the details for the location based on whatever the dataset returns.